# How to access SysDump menu on Samsung Galaxy S5, Android 5.0

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, internal-storage, samsung-galaxy-s-5

My Samsung Galaxy S5 tells me I have insufficient storage to update apps.  Looking at the storage menu, I have enough space, and it will work if I clear the cache through the storage menu.  This is only a temporary fix, though.  I had 21 updates this morning and I had to clear the cache 6 times just to update them.  Looking on Google I found many people suggesting accessing the `SysDump` menu and deleting the `dumpstate/logcat` to fix this issue.  However, everyone says to dial `*#9900#` in the dialer to access this.  This does not work on my phone, maybe because I have Android 5.0, and most of these articles and posts were written years ago.  How can I access the SysDump menu?

Or is there a better solution for this?  I only have 512MB free of 16GB, however, most apps are <30MB.  I see 5.56GB in `Miscellaneous files` though when I look through them they add up to 105MB.

Comment: See if the answers here help: [Getting "Storage space running out" message in Galaxy S4; \*#9900# does not show any menu](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/119574)

Comment: That didn't help.  Deleting `/root/sdcard/DCIM/.thumbnails` cleared up only 10 MB.  `LOST.DIR` doesn't appear to exist on my internal memory.  And `/data/media` doesn't contain anything, because my phone isn't rooted.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind to update apps it needs something like 3x the actual size. Not sure why you want a sysdump/logcat as your only real solution is just to clear space from device. Install an app like [DiskUsage](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.diskusage&hl=en) that allows you to see how the space is being used and start clearing up space.

As to your actual question if you need a logcat, enable developer options (settings/about and tap 3+ times build number), enable adb and use logcat command through the pc using [adb](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat.html).

Also through adb you can you can run adb shell and dump dmesg (kernel log).

Answer (score 0):

download [CM LITE](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cmcm.lite) and scan junk files.
It cleares up all the cached data,  unnecessary residuals.
Check if you have any previous obb files of games uncleaned.. if you are a gamer. 
If that didn't work,  set file manager to reveal hidden files and check every folder for misc. files.
hope this helped..

Comment: Can you please edit your answer and add a link to the app from the play store?