# storage space running out, wont let me download anything

Tags: applications, insufficient-memory

My phone says that I am running out of storage. when I try to download an App to get rid of some of it, it just keeps telling me that I have insufficient storage

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Storage space running out. Some system functions may not work](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/60897/storage-space-running-out-some-system-functions-may-not-work)

Answer (score -1):

First, delete one of the extra apps to make some space. Then install [Link2SD](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.buak.Link2SD) app. This app can move your apps installed in internal storage to memory card, which makes more free space.

Comment: Nobody asked for a crack and neither such request would be entertained here. So, are you affiliated to www.freedownloadok.com to which you linked the app in [first revision](http://android.stackexchange.com/revisions/139884/1)?